# Sudoku machine-readable text

Tags: discussion

Looking at:

[Stuck on this Sudoku!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68663/stuck-on-this-sudoku)

can we make it obligatory for the Sudoku grid to be also disclosed as the usual 81 character string, in this case:

> 370451200400706010001000407000170649700009020190000375000020000257803004000000082

without guesses:

> 370050200400706010001000000000170640000009000090000305000020000057800004000000082

(although I prefer for validating purposes)

> 370451200 400706010 001000407 000170649 700009020 190000375 000020000 257803004 000000082

and:

> 370050200 400706010 001000000 000170640 000009000 090000305 000020000 057800004 000000082

for rapid entry into say:

http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm

Comment: Not sure what the practical effect of such a rule would be: if the OP was aware of the existence of such websites, they likely would not be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @ffao; do you know which website the OP is using? do they have a 'to text' output option?